# How to use the streams in login page in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, clean-architecture

I want to make when the user already has logged in he has to redirect to the home page else he has to redirect to the login page using Streams. So anyone please can u help me?
Also, this application is based on clean architecture.
So advise me to become a pro of clean architecture... Because this architecture ruining my life..

Comment: I recommend you start with that https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/overview

Comment: Read this https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/super-simple-authentication-flow-with-flutter-firebase-737bba04924c

Comment: @EyaS I have completed the authentication part. But stuck with this login verification using Stream. and thank you for the reply

Comment: @ProblematicDude Thanks, buddy for your concern